# Allegro5 está instalado pero no funciona (Fedora 36)

Tags: c++, eclipse, librería, fedora, allegro

He estado intentando compilar un programa usando la librería allegro 5 y escribir #include<allegro5/allegro.h> para poder usarla no da ningún error, pero a la hora de usar cualquier función de la librería me devuelve un error y dice que "no están definidas".

````
Building target: AllegroTesting
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++  -o "AllegroTesting" ./src/allegrotest.o ./src/test2.o   
/usr/bin/ld: ./src/test2.o: en la función `main':
/home/efeme/Programacion/Eclipse/AllegroTesting/Debug/../src/test2.cpp:5: definiciones múltiples de `main'; ./src/allegrotest.o:/home/efeme/Programacion/Eclipse/AllegroTesting/Debug/../src/allegrotest.cpp:6: primero se definió aquí
/usr/bin/ld: ./src/allegrotest.o: en la función `main':
/home/efeme/Programacion/Eclipse/AllegroTesting/Debug/../src/allegrotest.cpp:8: referencia a `al_install_system' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: /home/efeme/Programacion/Eclipse/AllegroTesting/Debug/../src/allegrotest.cpp:10: referencia a `al_create_display' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: /home/efeme/Programacion/Eclipse/AllegroTesting/Debug/../src/allegrotest.cpp:12: referencia a `al_map_rgb' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: /home/efeme/Programacion/Eclipse/AllegroTesting/Debug/../src/allegrotest.cpp:12: referencia a `al_clear_to_color' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: ./src/test2.o: en la función `main':
/home/efeme/Programacion/Eclipse/AllegroTesting/Debug/../src/test2.cpp:8: referencia a `al_install_system' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: /home/efeme/Programacion/Eclipse/AllegroTesting/Debug/../src/test2.cpp:13: referencia a `al_create_display' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: /home/efeme/Programacion/Eclipse/AllegroTesting/Debug/../src/test2.cpp:19: referencia a `al_map_rgb' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: /home/efeme/Programacion/Eclipse/AllegroTesting/Debug/../src/test2.cpp:19: referencia a `al_clear_to_color' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: /home/efeme/Programacion/Eclipse/AllegroTesting/Debug/../src/test2.cpp:20: referencia a `al_flip_display' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: /home/efeme/Programacion/Eclipse/AllegroTesting/Debug/../src/test2.cpp:21: referencia a `al_rest' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: /home/efeme/Programacion/Eclipse/AllegroTesting/Debug/../src/test2.cpp:22: referencia a `al_destroy_display' sin definir
collect2: error: ld devolvió el estado de salida 1
make: *** [makefile:58: AllegroTesting] Error 1
"make all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los errores son del linker porque no puede encontrar las funciones que te dice.

Para usar una librería debes indicarle al compilador donde están los archivos .h para poder acceder a ellos con llaves angulares (`<librería.h>`) y lo más importante, dónde encontrarla.

En [la documentación](https://github.com/liballeg/allegro_wiki/wiki/Quickstart#compile-and-run) te da un ejemplo de como deberías compilarlo:

```
gcc hello.c -o hello $(pkg-config allegro-5 allegro_font-5 --libs --cflags)
```

---

Si así no funciona, tiened que decirle al linker que tenga en cuenta las librerías con el parámetro `-l<librería>`. En Linux siguen la nomenclatura `lib<librería>.so`. Por ejemplo, si la librería se llama `liballegro.so`, el parámetro sería `-lallegro`.

También tienes que indicar la carpeta donde se encuentran con el parámetro `-L<ruta>`. Por ejemplo, si están en la carpeta `lib/allegro` el parámetro sería `-Llib/allegro`.